# AWS SAM + ApiGateway + x-amazon-integration + SNS fifo + SQS fifo: MessageGroupId from path param

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-sam, aws-api-gateway

I am writing a SAM template for a business application that, among other things, processes device status updates.

Users post status updates to the API Gateway that, in turn, suitably sets the `destSQS` message attribute and publishes such requests to an SNS topic.
Several SQS queues are subscribed to the topic and messages are routed depending on the value of `destSQS`. The following is the `AWS::SNS::Subscription` resource definition for the SQS queue of interest for this question.

```
  StatusUpdatesQueueSubscription: # accept msg iff destSQS is "StatusUpdates"
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Endpoint: !Join [ "-", [ !Sub "arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${AWS::StackName}", !Ref StatusUpdatesQueueName ] ]
      Protocol: sqs
      FilterPolicy:
        destSQS:
          - "StatusUpdate"
      RawMessageDelivery: True
      TopicArn: !Ref DispatcherSNSTopic
```

So far everything works with "simple" (i.e., non-FIFO) SNS/SQS.
The following is the relevant section of the current OpenAPI (3.0.0) configuration embedded in the SAM template.

```
/devices/{device_id}/status:  
  post:
    parameters:
      - in: path
        name: device_id
        description: String ID of a device
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
          description: Device unique identifier
    security:
      - ApiKeyAuth: [ ]
    requestBody:
      description: A status update for a device
      required: true
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object            
    responses:
      "202":
        description: Accepted
    x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
      type: "aws"
      httpMethod: "POST"
      uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:sns:action/Publish"
      credentials: !GetAtt DispatcherSNSTopicAPIRole.Arn
      requestParameters:
        integration.request.querystring.Message: "method.request.body"
        integration.request.querystring.TopicArn: !Sub "'${DispatcherSNSTopic}'"
        integration.request.querystring.MessageAttributes.entry.1.Name: "'destSQS'"
        integration.request.querystring.MessageAttributes.entry.1.Value.DataType: "'String'"
        integration.request.querystring.MessageAttributes.entry.1.Value.StringValue: "'StatusUpdate'"
      responses:
        default:
          statusCode: 202
```

Now, I want to enrich this configuration to group messages by device_id (so that status updates for the same device will be processed in order).

I've already modified the template `Resources` section so that SQS queues and the topic are FIFO and tried to add the following mapping:

```
        integration.request.querystring.MessageAttributes.entry.2.Name: "MessageGroupId"
        integration.request.querystring.MessageAttributes.entry.2.Value.DataType: "'String'"
        integration.request.querystring.MessageAttributes.entry.2.Value.StringValue: method.request.path.device_id
```

but I get the following error:

```
   Resource handler returned message: "Errors found during import:
    Unable to put integration on 'POST' for resource at path '/devices/{device_id}/status': Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: MessageGroupId]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of searches and attempts, I've found the solution.
Perhaps sharing is useful for someone in the future.

1. `MessageGroupId` has to be set as a child of `querystring` and not as a `MessageAttribute`, as follows:

```
integration.request.querystring.MessageGroupId: "method.request.path.device_id"
```

2. the error was due to a syntax error: static strings must be enclosed by single quotes (and possibly, in turn, by double ones)

```
   integration.request.querystring.MessageAttributes.entry.2.Name: "'MyAttributeName'"
```